# Redirect linux console on boot

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, console, raspberry-pi

Is it possible on boot to redirect the console output to a `screen` session? The server has no monitor attached, and I'd like to be able to see the primary console output. I've seen other posts about redirecting to a serial port, but I'd rather use `screen` if possible, or another method to see the console output when logged in over SSH.

The box is running Raspbian Linux (Debian Wheezy).

Comment: But at boot, neither screen nor sshd will have been started yet! Still, it must be possible somehow, at least when it's a virtual machine that's booting, since this is what Linode does. If it's a physical machine that's booting, I'll be surprised to hear that it is really possible.

Comment: Can you not just read `/var/log/boot` once you have logged in?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a screen session to the inittab at a specific run level :

```
# GNU Screen on runlevel 4
scr2:4:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin <user> tty1 linux
```

Where <user> is your user.

Then configure grub to output to that device.

```
# (0) Arch Linux
title  Arch Linux Screen
root   (hd0,2)
kernel /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/disk/your_disk ro acpi_no_auto_ssdt irqpoll 4
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
```